# How to turn off or 'uncheck' Render->Lock Interface

Tags: interface

Problem:  I simply cannot find a way to uncheck the "Lock Interface' checkbox under Render

Using Blender 2.83.4

Clicking it (left, middle, right) or combo key click (shift-click, shift left click, etc), nothing works.

My renders tend to take a while so I do like to move around the use the interface for simple tasks.

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: in the python console (Shift + F4) type: `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.use_lock_interface = False`

Comment: perfect!   it worked and many many thanks.  that was a frustrating one...

Comment: *File > Defaults > Load Factory Setting*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it in Blender2.8x&2.9 and found that opening "**Graswald Pro(V1.3.0)**" would cause this problem, and closing the plugin would restore normal.

Comment: In 3.0 I have the same issue, it seems like Lodify caused it this time

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you can't disable the option by just clicking on the box, but you can always use the python command for most operations in blender.

In the python console (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) type:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.use_lock_interface = True
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: @brockmann why is it better to use `context` and not `data`?

Comment: Tried to explained it in the revision title. It's always *current* scene and you don't have to worry about specifing the name of the scene. Also better practice in this case since the OP wants to change that setting in the current scene (the scene in context) Does that make sense @susu ?

Comment: @brockmann thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: You're welcome @susu